# Angular js ngRoute redirect to new page without ng-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

I have a webapplication dashboard.. I made the header common across all the html files.. It has profile page, page 1 and SignIn. And i have signIn page which should not contain the common header. how to redirect to signin.html without ng-view and common header..

```
var app=angular.module('single-page-app',['ngRoute']);
app.config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){
    //HTML5 Location # remove
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
          enabled: true,
          requireBase: false
    });
      $routeProvider
          .when('/profile',{
                templateUrl: 'profile.html',
                controller:'profilecntrl'
          })
          .when('/page1',{
                templateUrl: 'page1.html',
                controller:'singlecntrl'
          }).
          when('/signIn',{
                templateUrl:'signIn.html'
          });

});
app.controller('MainController',function($scope){

});
```

And My main Header file HTML is

```
 <!-- HEADER AND NAVBAR -->
        <header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Angular Routing</a>
                </div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="/profile">Profile</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/page1">Page 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/signIn">Sign In</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            </nav>
        </header>

        <!-- MAIN CONTENT AND INJECTED VIEWS -->
            <div ng-view=""></div>
```

I have separate Sign In HTML file where ng-view is not included and Header is not included... how to redirect to signIn html using ng-Route..

Comment: you don't.  if `/signIn.html` isn't using `ng-view`, then it's a separate angular app.  You can have an `href` to it, but the `$routeProvider` for this angular app can't manage it.  You should consider taking a page from other routers like uiRouter, and nest your `ng-view` elements.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can hide the header if user is on sign in page

HTML:

```
<header ng-if="currentPage !== '/signIn'">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Angular Routing</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="/profile">Profile</a></li>
                <li><a href="/page1">Page 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="/signIn">Sign In</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('MainController',function($scope, $location){
    $scope.currentPage = $location.path();
});
```